# How i can justifiate the time of my algorithm in nanosecond

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, if-statement, time

[image: My Algorithm]

Hello I would like to  know how I can justify the time taken to execute this algorithm

My proposition for this algorithm is: 150+180N (is the length of F[])

Comment: `System.nanoTime();` method?

Comment: You can benchmark your code and then take the average time over all runs. (Is that code written in comic sans? *twitches*)

Comment: But who is HAL ?

Comment: Without seeing the table with the constants the question in the image is referring to, this question can't possibly be answered. Also please post the text as plain-text instead of a picture in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool for micro benchmarking.  https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/ is a project page where they wrote JMH, a Java micro benchmark tool.

You can integrate this tool into various projects in various ways.  One way (if you are using Apache's Maven) is detailed here https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness

Do not attempt to build your own code to capture timings.  The timings of the JVM are not stable, simple, or consistent; unless you want to learn about and account for warm-up, JIT, in-lining, permgen, and a lot of JVM internals, odds are any tool you build will report incorrect information.